# Pathfinder Differential Correction: "Use reference position from" who?

Tags: gps

How do you choose either "base files" or "base provider"?

[image: Pathfinder Office Differential Correction]

Comment: May depend on the provider. This web site, http://www.compasstoolsinc.com/basestationdata.htm, says that their base stn provides NAD83 (CORS96) if you use the base files or WGS84 (ITRF) if you use the reference position.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your own base file from same picture select the Reference possition>select reference possition from base provider>then click "select". 
In this window select new and add here the name whatever you want and enter the base station coordinate of your base station. In this way chose the base file and chose the base provider what you entered and apply differencial correction.